Timeout server web Api Net8
No detecta timeout en controlador web Api usando Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Timeouts
Implementación:
Program.cs agrego:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Timeouts;
builder.Services.AddRequestTimeouts();
app.UseRequestTimeouts();

En Controlador agrego un timeout de 10 segundos:
[HttpPost]
[RequestTimeout(10000)]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] PedidoBasico pedidoBasico)

El server no lo ejecuto en modo debug tal como lo indica la documentación.
Debería cortar a los 10 segundos, pero NO lo hace.

Por las dudas: UseRequestTimeouts()  lo estas usando después de UseRouting() ?

Sí Patricio, lo uso luego de UseRouting()
